# strictly monotonic and range open

Tags: continuity

Prove that a strictly monotonic function with range open set is continuous. I have proved for case when range is connected set.

Further question: How to prove f continuous when range is closed set.

Problem 4.65 Mathematical Analysis Apostol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a monotonic function, how many possible discontinuities does it has?By the way, where is the CAP... box? The system ask me whether i'm a human being.

Comment: there are countable no. of discontinuity. But how it helps. And discontinuity are only jump discontinuity. What is CAP...Box

Comment: for an $x_0$ that is a discontinuous point, where should $f(x_0)$ be placed at the interval $[f(x_0-0), f(x_0+0)]$ to make the range still open?

Comment: Ok got the hint. One more question how to prove f continuous when range is closed

Comment: You still may use the previous discussion.

Comment: Thanks a lot. took time but able to prove using only hint given by you